# Submenu in Menu Bar enable disable

Tags: wpf, menu, submenu

I have following xaml for menu bar:

```
<Menu Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="FILE">
            <MenuItem Header="New Search" Click="miNewSearch"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Open Search" Click="miOpenSearch"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Save" Click="miSaveSearch"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Save As"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Open/New Database" Click="miOpenNewDB"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="miExitApp"/>
        </MenuItem>            
    </Menu>
```

My requirement is to disable a submenu when select File menu, which event handler should I use, I have searched it but have not found any answer for it. I have used "Click" event on Menuitem like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="FILE" Click="eventhandler">
```

But eventhanler is getting executed after selecting any submenu item. Please help, i am new to WPF.

Comment: where is your xaml snippet? :)

Comment: sorry,now I have edited it

Comment: use MVVM and commands here. If you use command u can use CanExecute of command to enable/disable menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MenuItem.SubmenuOpened](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.submenuopened%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

so

```
<MenuItem Header="FILE"
          SubmenuOpened="MenuItem_OnSubmenuOpened">
```

with

```
private void MenuItem_OnSubmenuOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  Debug.WriteLine("Called");
}
```

should get invoked when the File menu is opened.